# Node Red javascript Convert a HEX string to a ACSII string

Tags: javascript

Ok I have 0 experience in writing javascript code.  I have a function node that needs to do the following.
I have a string, say `var stringA = '31323334353637'`, this represents a 7 byte array, in hex.  I need to change that to a ACSII sting, `var stringB = '1234567'`.

Will someone please help, I know there should be a simple way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can at least search before you post a new question though. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hex+to+ascii

Comment: I do apologize, I have been searching for two nights and have no idea why I did not come across that thread.  But thanks for the reply anyway.